# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!' swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

hey guys just wondering if you could help me debug this, this error comes up but only when i add a ui text view to a view controller here is everything i have for the view controller code as you can see i tried dispatchQueue but doesn't do anything.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            weak var textview: UITextView!
            }
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, show the code that working with this controller.

Comment: It is kind of weird that you would need to declare `weak var textview: UITextView!` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `viewDidLoad`! why would you do such a thing?

Comment: i did it after reading other threads with a similar error it didnt make much sense to me but i thought i may as well try it seeing as other people said it fixed their problem

Comment: You should show the original code that is causing the error without any of the fixes you have tried.

Comment: Is this `ViewController` your first view controller that loads when you run the app? Meaning, ___is this your entry point view controller___? If not, show how you are navigating to this view controller.

Comment: it is not the entry point view controller it is one i have added for the entry point to go to, bellow is one of the conditions that trigger the segue

Comment: if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                i = i + 1
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Location", sender: self)
                // Notification permission was already granted
            }

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable out side the viewDidLoad

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

       var textview: UITextView!


                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
                }

                override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
                    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
                }
            }
```

Comment: still coming up with the same error is there anything else i can add to help people figure out what is wrong

Comment: ive added the debug log sorry for the messy layout

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone Kaushik meant add the log to your question , not attempt to add it to their answer

Comment: i edited the question to add the log, im sorry im new to posting to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with this controller from not-main thread. I think that you're trying to show the controller from some closure or async call. You have to ensure that your UI calls only from main thread.

Also you can debug it. Before you create/instantiate this controller set breakpoint and pay attention on debug navigator in XCode, you will be able to see where the program stopped, is this main thread or not.[image]

Comment: litterally all i was trying to do was add a uitextview to a second view controller, i had already done it successfully with one controller and was simply wanting to do the same with another except it threw this error. i originally just added the text view to the controller with no code at all anything else has been done due to trying to find help online

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone please, show how you invoke controller which trigger the error. Or is it just "show" segue in storyboard?

Comment: i use show segue in storyboard and the segue is performed once a user notification status has been determined.

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone I see, and by this point I think it's a reason of your problem :) Please, show the code which performs this segue from user notification status.

Comment: if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                i = i + 1
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Location", sender: self)
                // Notification permission was already granted
            }

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone Try to add this code: print(Thread.isMainThread ? "it's main thread" : "it is NOT main thread") before perform segue and see what console will write. And as I understand this code performing inside closure?

Comment: where would it print in the console

Comment: i can not see it printing anywhere

Comment: I'll add screenshots to my answer

Comment: did you add them ?

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone yes, I did

Comment: it didnt print it at all i scanned the entire log so that must be the issue

Comment: If it isn't critical you can share entire project with me and I'll try to help

Comment: how would i do that im new to stack overflow

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone I've added my contacts in "About me" in my profile